# how to get unequal numbers in java for this program?

Tags: java

```
//to display second smallest number out of three  
import java.util.*;
public class Prog
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    int a,b,c,d,e;
    System.out.println("Enter three numbers");
    a = in.nextInt();
    b = in.nextInt();   
    c = in.nextInt();
    d = Math.min(a, b);
    e = Math.max(d,c);
    System.out.println(+e);
  }
}
```

I have made this code but I want that when the user inputs the numbers they are unequal, how can I do so with this program?

Comment: You mean to force user to input unequal numbers? or I can't understand your question properly?

Comment: In the question, it says to accept three numbers and display the second smallest number using math.max and math.min, so is there any way through which I get three "unequal number" or this is the right way.

Comment: Yes, for example: Sample input : 31,82,61.Sample Output : 61

Comment: Store your number in a Set, for example, and check if the Set already contains the number that user submit. If it contains don't accept the number and simply print smth like 'nubmers should be unique, please enter another number' and wait for next number to be submitted from user

Comment: What if user enters 4, 2, 9. d = 2 and e = 9. Your code breaks

Comment: How can I fix it, I cannot come up with any other way of finding the second smallest number?

Comment: Why not add the numbers to an array/list or collection and sort them?

Comment: Use collections. Many have suggested the same in the comments. Sort using any Java collection and your answer will be last middle number/last but one number (from the smallest side).

Comment: Sorry I'm new to java I have to use Math.max and Math.min, how can do I make a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is according to your question and comments in the question that you will have only 3 inputs and you want to find 2nd smallest and you have to use min and max only.
If it is not the case update the question for the correct answer to your intended question.

```
  int d=a+b+c;
  int e=Math.max(a,Math.max(b,c));
  int f=Math.min(a,Math.min(b,c));
  System.out.println(d-(e+f));
```

Comment: That's the reason why I mentioned in the answer that this will solve 3 numbers

Comment: This is showing the correct result but with opposite sign, how do I correct it?

Comment: min and max will give correct output for any values

Comment: I was saying that if the answer is 4 the result says "-4" but I corrected it by changing:  `System.out.println(d - (e + f));`

Comment: yeah ! I modified

Answer (score 0):

What you have is close, but in order to ensure you get 3 unique numbers and that you accurately return the middle number, I'd suggest using something like the following.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> enteredValues = getEnteredValues();
    if (enteredValues.size() != 3) {
        // something went terribly wrong, but just to be safe
    } else {
        int a = enteredValues.get(0);
        int b = enteredValues.get(1);
        int c = enteredValues.get(2);
        int min = Math.min(a, Math.min(b, c));
        int max = Math.max(a, Math.max(b, c));
        if (a > min && a < max) {
            // a is mid
        } else if (b > min && b < max) {
            // b is mid
        } else {
            // c is mid
        }
}

private static List<Integer> getEnteredValues() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> enteredValues = new LinkedList<>();
    System.out.println("Enter 3 unique numbers");
    while (enteredValues.size() < 3) {
        Integer enteredValue = in.nextInt();
        if (enteredValues.contains(enteredValue)) {
          // probably prompt them to enter another number
        } else {
            enteredValues.add(enteredValue);
        }
    }
    return enteredValues;
}
```

So what this does is first get the 3 numbers from the user. It'll force them to enter 3 unique numbers by only adding their input to the collection if it's unique.

After it fetches the numbers from the user, it'll use Math.min and Math.max to get the min and max between all 3 numbers. Then, it's just a simple if/else tree to figure out which one lies in between the calculated min/max.

I hope this helps!